# Brightness and volume key bindings not working in dwm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro, brightness, dwm, volume

I'm trying to get my volume and brrightness keys to work using dwm. I put this into dwm/config.h:

```
static const char *upvol[] = {"/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "0", "+5%", NULL };
static const char *downvol[] = {"/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "0", "-5%", NULL };
static const char *mutevol[] = {"/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-mute", "0", "toggle", NULL };

static const char *brightnessup[] = {"sudo", "xbacklight", "-inc", "5", NULL };
static const char *brightnessdown[] = {"sudo", "xbacklight", "-dec", "5", NULL };
```

And also this for the keybinds in static Key keys[].

```
{ MODKEY,       XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume,  spawn, {.v = downvol} },
{ MODKEY        XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume,  spawn, {.v = upvol} },
{ MODKEY,       XF86XK_AudioMute,         spawn, {.v = mutevol} },
{ MODKEY,       XF86XK_MonBrightnessUp,   spawn, {.v = brightnessup} },
{ MODKEY,       XF86XK_MonBrightnessDown, spawn  {.v = brightnessdown} },
```

So far I've tried this in my command line

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
```

Then I tried to do the same in root, but that didn't change anything either I also killed xsessions and booted everything up again and it still doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Comment: It seems that you prefixed your key bindings with `MODKEY`. If you want to omit `MODKEY`, just replace them with `0`. Another thing, `xbacklight` works fine without `sudo` on my machine. If this does not work for you try to remove `sudo`.